# Mostrar/ocultar menus en funcion del perfil/role de usuario

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Buenas, mi consulta básicamente es orientarme a como solucionar mi problema de la manera más optima,

Tengo una web con backend en nodejs donde envío los ficheros estáticos (no uso plantillas jade), todas las modificaciones las hago con javascript y llamadas ajax, mi duda es como montar un menu (navbar) en funcion de permisos de usuario .. adminitrador, usuario normal...

El back lo tengo montado y en función del role puedo mandar un html u otro pero me parece excesivo tener que duplicar miles de páginas para cambiar solo el memu donde aparezca alguna opción más.

Otra opcion es cambiarlo en el front desde un js pero me parece más vulnerable.

¿Alguien me orienta un poco?

Gracias

Comment: ¿estás usando SQL o NoSQL?

Comment: mongodb, tengo el role guardado en la session

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1):

> **Advertencia**: El código presentado aquí no ha sido probado. Es probable que se encuentren errores de código o typo que se debe arreglar.

---

> No estoy usando plantillas

Deberías usar, es decir, si deseas hacer algo cuyas posibilidades se ven limitadas de una forma, debes buscar alguna otra forma que te brinde la posibilidad de hacerlo.

---

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente diagrama ER (Ya sé que es NoSQL, pero es solo para ilustración):

[image]

Podemos deducir que:

- Un `Permiso` es el acceso dado a un `Rol` sobre determinado `SubMenu`.
- Un `Rol` es un conjunto de `Permisos` predeterminados, dándole un nombre. Por ejemplo, el `Rol` `Administrador` puede tener permisos para:

  - Leer
  - Eliminar
  - Editar
  - Banear ;)

Con estos datos podriamos armar un esquema en Mongo.

#### Creación de los modelos

**Role**

```
const RoleSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Permission'
    }]
});
```

**Permission**

```
const PermissionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

**MenuItem**

```
const MenuItemSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    permissions: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Permission',
        required: true
    }]
});
```

**Menu**

```
const MenuSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: '#'
    },
    roles: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'Role'
    }],
    items: [{
        type: String,
        ref: 'MenuItem'
    }]
});
```

---

Una vez que tienes todo el esquema, restan hacer 2 cosas:

1. Cuando el usuario inicie sesión, traer el menú de acuerdo a su rol.
2. Ese menú se debe procesar en el `view engine` en orden de construir el menú.

#### Creando el menú con Handlebars

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es obtener los menúes y los ítems de acuerdo al rol y permisos del usuario (asumo que sabes consultar en Mongo). Luego, creamos el menú completo en `handlebars`.

**menu.hbs**

```
<ul class="menu">
    {{#each menus as menu}}
        {{#ifRoleAllowed menu.roles id ../user.roles}}
            <li>
                <a href="{{menu.url}}">
                    {{menu.label}}
                </a>
                <ul>
                    {{#each menu.items as item}}
                        {{#ifPermInRole item.permissions id ../user.roles}}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{item.url}}">
                                    {{item.label}}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {{/ifPermInRole}}
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {{/ifRoleAllowed}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

El helper `ifRoleAllowed` y `ifPermInRole` no pertenecen a `Handlebars`. Handlebars te permite extenderlo mediante helpers personalizados. Así, podemos crear un helper que nos diga si el usuario está permitido para la acción de ese menú y/o item:

**ifRoleAllowed**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifRoleAllowed', function(mroles, uroles, options) {
  let isAllowed = false;
  mroles.forEach(mrole => {
    if(!isAllowed) {
        uroles.forEach(urole => {
            // son roles iguales
          if(urole === mrole) {
            isAllowed = true;   
          }
        });
    }
  });

  if(isAllowed) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

**ifPermInRole**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifPermInRole', function(perms, roles, options) {
  let isAllowed = false;
  perms.forEach(perm => {
    if(!isAllowed) {
        roles.forEach(role => {
          if(role.contains(perm)) {
            isAllowed = true;
          }
        });
    }
  });

  if(isAllowed) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Comment: era reacio a las plantillas ya que solo había visto jade, al final me he puesto a usar EJS y de matavilla.

Comment: Yep, EJS también es bueno, aunque prefiero Handlebars por su flexibilidad. Asegúrate usar [este EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) porque el antiguo ya no tiene soporte.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en PHP lo hago algo asi:

En la navbar agrego un condicional, que si tiene tal permiso aparezca tal cosa, por ejemplo, soy administrador y tengo que ver el panel del control en la navbar.

```
if($_SESSION['rol'] == 'admin') {
  <li>Panel de control</li>
}
```

Es eso lo que estas buscando?

Saludos!

Comment: Podría llegar a valerme, pero yo no uso PHP solo javascript , jquery, como accedo a las variables de session?